# Illustrator: Export artboards using artboard name as file title

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I want to use the artboard's name for the file name when exporting.

Is there a method to configure Illustrator to use the artboard name as the file name upon export?

Comment: Hi Manolo. I've edited your question to be a bit more clear. If you feel my edit was unwarranted, please click the [EDIT](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/100146/edit) link under the question and revise as you see fit. Thanks.

Comment: And this is a possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9216/export-multiple-artboards-to-pngs-named-after-the-artboard-without-the-filename

Answer (score 3):

In the `Save As...` or `Export` dialogue, check `Use Artboards`. If you keep the default artboard names, only numbers will be added to the main file name. If you rename the artboards, the new name will be added to the main file name. I don't know how to avoid that the main file name is added before the artboard name. I usually use file renamimg tools (eg. BetterFileRenamer on Mac) to fix those things in a simple drag'n drop procedure.

Comment: This seems not to work anymore... Though it used to. Is there any *new* way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the Artboards and then use "Export for screens". This will export with artboard names only.